# How to create this type of subdomain on the fly like Blogger.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, subdomain, blogger

Sometime ago I asked this question and I was told that the entry has to be made in DNS etc. I was not sure whether all this is really required or not. The kind of feature that I am looking for is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see blogger lets the user choose the subdomain for his blog. How can we achieve this? I am basically developing in asp.net C#. How can I allow my users to choose subdomains like this once I have my top level domain. Currently I am developing on localhost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a wild card domain in IIS so it traps every request to the top level domain and under.

In **asp.net**: Create an HttpModule...  this will run for every request and you can check the domain name, etc and pull in user information based on the sub-domain. An example httpmodule can be found at [URL Rewriting in ASP.NET via HttpModule](http://www.upfromthesky.com/blog/post/2009/05/04/URL-Rewriting-in-ASPNET-via-HttpModule.aspx).

In **asp.net mvc**: Create a custom RouteHandler (custom based on interface IRouteHandler). Look at [RouteHandler vs ControllerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419420/routehandler-vs-controllerfactory) question for an example.

Comment: How do I add wildcard DNS Mapping in IIS 7.5? The article I am referring is `http://www.purpleant.com/Blogs/BrianSwanson/tabid/64/EntryId/144/Wildcard-sub-domain-for-Microsoft-IIS-and-DNS.aspx` but this is of IIS 6. How can I do it in IIS 7.5?

Comment: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/

Comment: It can also be done **without** writing an HttpModule by using [IIS UrlRewrite 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).  You setup the format of your url in the web.config and then you can access that value via the querystring.

Comment: Sadly the first link seems to be dead, getting 404 error.

Comment: Yes, it appears that link is dead.  But fear not - MS has information on that as well:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a wildcard DNS mapping that maps `*.example.com` to your webserver, and a wildcard hostname mapping telling IIS to send all subdomains to your ASP.Net website.

You can then check `Request.Hostname` in server-side code and use the appropriate content (or error message)

Comment: How do I add wildcard DNS Mapping in IIS 7.5? The article I am referring is `http://www.purpleant.com/Blogs/BrianSwanson/tabid/64/EntryId/144/Wildcard-sub-domain-for-Microsoft-IIS-and-DNS.aspx` but this is of IIS 6. How can I do it in IIS 7.5?