# Set up virtual path for the IIS application

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, virtualhost

I have the ASP.NET application deployed on IIS with the host name : www.testweb.com. Assume there are different users and each of them needs unique URL to access the website. So for each of them new Application is created by their name and, for example, John user will access application like http://www.testweb.com/John

Now for every user I want to modify URL, provided by default, to say http://john.testweb.com. Is there a way to make it inside the same host machine ?

Comment: you need to deal with sub folders and sub domains. Check with http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/537441/ASP-NETplus-plusCreateplusSubplusdomainplusforplus

Comment: You can also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638923/how-to-create-this-type-of-subdomain-on-the-fly-like-blogger-com